# CSS elements not all being applied to webpage?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why most of the CSS is not being applied. Is it to do with specificity? It was all being applied correctly, then I added an img element, after which nothing worked, I have removed the img but still noting works, I have looked throught both the CSS and HTML and cannot find any problem....

```css
/* * {
  
} */


#title1 {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: oblique;
    text-decoration:#D8E2DC;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 300px;
    left: 100px;
    font-family:  'Newsreader', serif;
    }

#title2 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: oblique;
    text-decoration:#000000;
    font-size: 50px;
    }
    
#body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FB8500;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    right: 130px;
    font-family: 'Newsreader', serif;
        }
            

#type {
    border: 1px solid #D8E2DC;
    background-color: #FFB703;
    border-style: solid;
    }
        
#price {
    border: 1px solid #D8E2DC;
    background-color: #F8EDEB;
    border-style: solid;
    }
        
#time {
border: 1px solid #D8E2DC;
background-color: #F8EDEB;
border-style: solid;
}

#navbuttons{
display: flex;
position: relative;
bottom:320px;
left: 300px;
}

#home {
background: none;
border-color: white;
color:white;
border: 2px solid;
padding: 20px;
font-size: 1em;
transition: color 0.25s, border-color 0.25s, box-shadow 0.25s,transform 0.25s;
}

        
#home:hover {
border-color: #a7b13f;
color: white;
box-shadow: 0 0.7em 0.7em -0.4em #aeb841;
transform: translateY(-0.25em);
cursor: pointer;
}


#about {
background: none;
color:white;
border: 2px solid;
padding: 20px;
font-size: 1em;
transition: color 0.25s, border-color 0.25s, box-shadow 0.25s,transform 0.25s;
}

        
#about:hover {
border-color: #a7b13f;
color: white;
box-shadow: 0 0.7em 0.7em -0.4em #aeb841;
transform: translateY(-0.25em);
cursor: pointer;
}

#contact {
    background: none;
    color:white;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: color 0.25s, border-color 0.25s, box-shadow 0.25s,transform 0.25s;
    }
    
            
#contact:hover {
    border-color: #f1ff5c;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.7em 0.7em -0.4em #f1ff5c;
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
    cursor: pointer;
    }

#signup {
    background: none;
    color:#ffffff;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: color 0.25s, border-color 0.25s, box-shadow 0.25s,transform 0.25s;
    }
    
            
#signup:hover {
    border-color: #f1ff5c;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.7em 0.7em -0.4em #f1ff5c;
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
    cursor: pointer;
    }

#body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FB8500;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    right: 130px;
    font-family: 'Newsreader', serif;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Newsreader:wght@200&family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Newsreader&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    
</head>

    <nav id="title1">
        <h1>Learn English with
        <span id=title2>David</span></h1>
        </nav>

<nav id="navbuttons">

    <ul id= "listbuttons">
 
        <button id="about" class="navigation"><a href="#about">About</a></button>
            
        <button id="contact" class="navigation"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></button>

        <button id="signup"class="navigation"><a href="#signup">Sign up</a></button>

        <button id="home"class="navigation"><a href="#home">Home</a></button>

    </ul>
        
</nav>
<body>
    
    <main>
       <section>
        <div id="table">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                <th id="type">Exam type</th>
                <th id="time">30 minutes</th>
                <th id="time">45 minutes</th>
                <th id="time">1 hour</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="type">IELTS</td>
                <td id="price">$15</td>
                <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="type">FCE</td>
                <td id="price">$15</td>
                <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">CAE</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">CAE</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">CPE</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">BEC</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">OGE</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">EGE</td>
                    <td id="price">$15</td>
                    <td id="price">$22.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="type">GRE</td>
                    <td id="price">$20</td>
                    <td id="price">$27.50</td>
                    <td id="price">$35</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>

        </section>

       <section id=flexpractice>
           <div style="background-color: #80ffdb"></div>
           <div style="background-color: #64dfdf"></div>
           <div style="background-color: #48bfe3"></div>
           <div style="background-color: #5390d9"></div>
           <div style="background-color: #6930c3"></div>
       </section>

    
    </main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ID should generally be used to reference a single element as it identifies that element. Where an ID is reused, class should be used instead

Comment: In your css file replace `#body` with `body`. In your html you have not used any id named `body`. If you do so, you will see the navbar. Also I agree with @Hive7's comment. You should use class instead.

Comment: Thank you, now I have the buttons back and colors but still cannot move anything, for some reason it is all inline now....